# Error in Production : The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I have created small Registration form application using Spring MVC and deployed in local machine. its working well[image]

Then i have converted whole project in to war file "app.war" and deployed in amazon web server,its showing following error

[image]

Comment: the log file will show useful information and with debug mode, it will show you something.

Comment: 404 means its not deployed.Kindly redeploy and try again

Comment: Its working when i deploy in local machine. its starts the application at localhost:8080, but when i deploy in server it shows extra path like ipadress:8080/appname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using standalone tomcat server on AWS. Standalone tomcat 
 server allow to host multiple web-apps on same server so distinguish between them we have to include context name in the url.

You can customize it by making changes in server.xml

```
 <Context docBase="app" path="customized_name" reloadable="true" swallowOutput="true"/>
```

Further, if you don't want to include context name in the url then you have to rename your war file to ROOT.war.